# "Function" with no args and no return type (void) in Java >= 8

Tags: java, java-8

I can define this myself e.g. this way:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface EmptyEmptyFunction {
    void apply();
}
```

and then use it as follows:

```
    EmptyEmptyFunction m = () -> {System.out.println("Hello World - Java 8!");};
    m.apply();
```

My question is: is there a built-in type in the JDK such as
`EmptyEmptyFunction`, or do I have to define `EmptyEmptyFunction`
myself (as I did already)?

There are many functional interfaces here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

but I don't seem to find one which has exactly
the same "signature" as my `EmptyEmptyFunction`.

Comment: There's no decent answer there so it's not duplicate, IMHO.

Comment: What's wrong with Runnable?

Comment: Well, I want to call `apply` on `m`, no? Not `run`. Or ... am I missing the point?

Comment: I'm sure that the existence of `Runnable` is why the Java designers felt they didn't need to add another functional interface.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you want the method to be called apply?  My understanding was that Java 8's lambdas just cares that the type has a single abstract method.  So, you could still pass in a lambda for a Runnable parameter.

Comment: @ajb Exactly so.

Comment: Actually my question is a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868733/java-8-equivalent-to-parameterless-action-with-void-return-type

Comment: @BrianGoetz If that is the case why was the `Supplier<T>` interface added if there was already `Callable<V>`?

Comment: @BrianGoetz I guess it's because `Callable<V>` can throw an `Exception`.

Comment: I disagree with the use `Runnable` advice. It miscommunicates intent: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76741622/501113