# Function Pointers as Parameters in Java 8

Tags: java, jpa, java-8

To reduce code duplication for every update of an attribute in JPA, I'd like to hand over a function pointer to `doTransaction` and invoke the function. How can I do that in Java 8?

```
public void modifySalary(Person person, float salary) {
    doTransaction(person.setSalary(salary));
}

public void doTransaction(final Function<Void, Void> func) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    func.apply(null);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could accept a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) as argument of `doTransaction` and pass it a lambda expression updating the person. Here, we are only using `Runnable` as a functional interface that defines a method taking no parameters and returning no value.

```
public void modifySalary(Person person, float salary) {
    doTransaction(() -> person.setSalary(salary));
}

public void doTransaction(Runnable action) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    action.run();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

---

If you think the name *Runnable* is somehow too linked to threads, you could roll your own interface defining a functional method taking no parameters and returning no value. For example, if you want to name it `Action`, you could have

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Action {
    void perform();
}
```

and then call `action.perform()` inside `doTransaction`.

Comment: I know that it's linked to threads. But it works without defining my own @FunctionInterface. Any ideas?

Comment: @msch Actually, that's the point I was making. In this case, we're just using it because it is an existing functional interface for taking no parameter and returning no value. There is no real link to threads whatsoever. The second part of my answer is just to provide an alternative name.

Comment: `Runnable` isn’t linked to threads. The API designers deliberately decided not to include a `void` noarg function in the `java.util.function` package because the already existing type `Runnable` fulfills this requirement.

Comment: @Holger Didn't know that, do you have a link for this? I'd be interested in reading why it was deliberatly done this way.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27973294/2711488) Brian Goetz confirms this in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need a parameterless void function, a `Runnable` would be sufficient.

```
public void modifySalary(Person person, float salary) {
  doTransaction(()->person.setSalary(salary));
}

public void doTransaction(Ruunable runnable) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    runnable.run();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```