# Pass static methods in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a class that times the average runtime of a method. I understand how to do that by running it 100 times and taking the average of it all. Example:

```
private long calculateAvg(){
    long totalTime = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++){
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        testMethod();
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        totalTime += (endTime - startTime);  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
    }
    return (totalTime / ITERATIONS);

}
```

Now I can set this to work for one static method but is there a way to pass different static methods into this to calculate instead of creating one of these for each method I want to test? If not, is there a design pattern that may work here? As of now, I am creating one of these methods for every other method I want to time and it doesn't seem efficient because I am reusing so much code.

Comment: Are you using Java 8? Tried the `Function` class?

Comment: I am using java 8 and I haven't tried either of these suggestions. I will have to research what each does.

Comment: Use an interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accept and run a `Runnable` argument:

```
private long calculateAvg(Runnable r) {
    //...
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    r.run();
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    //...
}
```

And call it like this:

```
long avg1 = calculateAvg(() -> testMethod());
long avg2 = calculateAvg(() -> testMethod2());
```

You might also want to consider some tips from [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: Very interesting. Does `() -> ` make it a Runnable argument?

Comment: Yes, it's a lambda. You can also use method references or anonymous classes if you prefer.

Comment: @user081608 "Does () -> make it a Runnable argument?" No. This syntax is for lambda expressions. On the other hand, `Runnable` is an interface with a single method named `run()`. Lambdas are a shortcut to the "old school" way of creating a class that implements an interface, often an anonymous inner class.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973294/function-with-no-args-and-no-return-type-void-in-java-8?lq=1#comment44339647_27973294

Comment: @Code-Apprentice **Wrong**.  They are suitable for any use of a method that has no return value and takes no parameters.  Note that when Java 8 introduced lambdas and method references, they also added a lot of standardized interface definitions for methods that take 0, 1, or 2 parameters and return or don't return a result.  But they didn't define an interface for the case of methods with no parameters and no result.  The reason they didn't?  Because Java already had `Runnable`.

Comment: @ajb Wow, great timing :)

Comment: @user081608 Not quite.  `() ->` _code_ makes it a lambda expression.  Roughly speaking, this lambda expression is a stand-in for any `interface` with one interface method that takes no parameters and returns no result (assuming the code doesn't have a `return` statement).  `Runnable` is one such interface, but there may be others.  Java actually looks at the type to expect from context, and based on that, it uses `Runnable` for the interface.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for the correction. I agree that lambdas are sutable when there is no return value, but they are not limited to methods with no parameters. You can also use lambdas for methods that take 1 or 2 parameters. Of course, in this instance, `()` means there are no parameters.

Comment: Note that instead of `calculateAvg(() -> testMethod());`, you can also save `calculateAvg(TestClass::testMethod);` if `TestClass` defines the static method `testMethod()` with no parameters or result.

Comment: @shmosel To improve your answer, you can show both the "old school" anonymous inner class way along with the lambda way. Then explain a little more about the differences. (I am suggesting this since the OP seems to be very new to Java and definitely should learn more about interfaces and classes.)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Right, I hope nobody tried to imply that they're limited to that.  You can use lambdas for methods that take any number of parameters, although for >= 3 parameters you won't find a built-in interface class in `java.util.function`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did [mention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941570/pass-static-methods-in-java/42941595?noredirect=1#comment72979975_42941595) the alternatives. I don't think they're relevant enough to include in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "pass methods", static nor non-static. Instead, you need to create an object reference created from a class which contains the method. Then you call the method on the object reference. In order to provide different implementations of a method, you create an `interface`. Then you can have many classes which implement that interface and the method which it declares. Now your timing code uses that interface to access the correct method.

```
public interface TheMethod {
    public void foo();
}

public class Method1 implements TheMethod {
    public void foo() {
        // code goes here 
    }
}

public class Method2 implements TheMethod {
    public void foo() {
        // code goes here 
    }
}
```

Now modify your timing method to accept a `TheMethod` instance:

```
private long calculateAvg(TheMethod method){
    // ...
    method.foo();
    // ...
}
```

Finally, you can call this method with different instances of classes which implement `TheMethod`:

```
TheMethod m1 = new Method1();
TheMethod m2 = new Method2();

long x = calculateAvg(m1);
long y = calculateAvg(m2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got two solutions may help for this question:
1. **Java reflection**:

```
public long calculateAvg(Object obj, String methodName) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, ClassNotFoundException{
    Method method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
    method.setAccessible(true);

    long totalTime = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        method.invoke(obj);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        totalTime += (endTime - startTime);  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
    }
    return (totalTime / ITERATIONS);
}
```

2. **Proxy Pattern**

You can learn about `proxy pattern`, you don't need to call the real method yourself, the proxy does. you can get the time before and after calling the real method. [proxy pattern tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/proxy_pattern.htm)

Comment: This looks wrong to me.  `method.invoke(clazz)` seems to assume that `method` is a method of the `Class` class, which it generally won't be.

Comment: Yes, you should pass the class instance as argument which the method belongs to.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying.  The point is, this code is broken.  It won't work in the form that you have it.

Answer (score 1):

No you cann't pass method in Java because methods are not first class citizen in Java, they are not `values`. The pattern to resolve this kind of problem is to use `anonymous class`. Take your case as example, you can define an `interface`:

```
@FunctionalInterface  // this annotation is available since jdk1.8
public interface Measurable {
    void measure();
}
```

And another `MeasureUtil` util class, methods inside it accept the type `Measurable`:

```
    public class MeasureUtil {
    private static final long ITERATIONS = 1000;

    public static long calculateAvg(Measurable measurable) {
        long totalTime = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++){
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            measurable.measure();
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();

            totalTime += (endTime - startTime);  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
        }
        return (totalTime / ITERATIONS);
    }
}
```

Then you `new` an instance of `Measurable` and pass it to `MeasureUtil.calculateAvg` each time:

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long avg = MeasureUtil.calculateAvg(new Measurable() {
            @Override
            public void measure() {
                method_under_mesure();
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Avg: " + avg);
    }

    private static void method_under_mesure() {
        System.out.println("call me");
    }
}
```

Since jdk1.8 Java starts to support `lambda expression`, which can make it much simpler and easier with the syntax sugar:

```
long avg = MeasureUtil.calculateAvg(() -> method_under_mesure());
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input, your method should be something like this

```
private long calculateAvg(Testable t){
  long totalTime = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++){
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    t.testMethod();
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();

    totalTime += (endTime - startTime);  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
  }
  return (totalTime / ITERATIONS);
}
```

Then, you should have an interface with a single method:

```
public interface Testable {
    public void testMethod();
}
```

In your main method, you have 3 ways to pass the method. Let's say you want to test a static sort method in SelectionSort class.

First: anonymous class (the traditional way)

```
calculateAvg(new Testable(){
    @Override
    public void testMethod(){
       SelectionSort.sort();
    }
})
```

Second: Lambda (Java 8)

```
calculateAvg(() -> SelectionSort.sort())
```

Third: Method Reference [Java 8 Method Reference: How to Use it](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx)

```
calculateAvg(SelectionSort::sort)
```