# java8 functional interface to handle the callback

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I have a generic private method which does common tasks and is used by other methods. The generic method has `if` and `else` conditions to support other methods that are called. Example:

```
private void myGenericMethod(String name, int age){
  common task1;
  common task2;
  if(name!= null && name.length > 0){
     specific task 1;
     specific task 2;
  } else{
     specific task 3;
     specific task 4;
  }
  if(age > 18){
     specific task 1`;
     specific task 2`;
  }
}
```

I want to use Java 8 lambda and I have created a functional interface called `Invoker` with a `invoke` method.

```
public interface Invoker{
  public void invoke()
}
```

Now my generic method looks like this and the public method handles the invoke function callback appropriately:

```
private void myGenericMethod(Invoker invoker){
  common task1;
  common task2;
  invoker.invoke();
}
```

Is there a functional interface in the JDK that I can use instead of creating this interface by myself?

Comment: You can have a look into the [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package and select which one suits your requirements. I couldn't suggest one because I don't know if your specific tasks has an argument (or more) ect ...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Package [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) does not contain a functional interface with a method that does not require any parameter and returns `void`. But you can use [**`Runnable`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface instead.

```
private void myGenericMethod(Runnable runnable){
    common task1;
    common task2;
    //consider checking if runnable != null to avoid NPE
    runnable.run();
}
```

Then the invocation would look pretty simple:

```
myGenericMethod(() -> {
    //do something fancy
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
});
```

#### Other options

There are other functional interfaces you may be interested in, for example:

- [`Supplier<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) if you want to return a value of `T` without passing any parameters
- [`Function<T,R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) if you want to pass a value of `T` and return a value of `R`
- [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) if you want to pass value `T` as a parameter and return `void`

#### Why there is no alternative for `Runnable` interface?

Using `Runnable` interface for a lambda that does not return nothing and does not expect any parameters may sound controversial for many programmers. `Runnable` was invented for running a code in a separate thread and many programmers identify this class with multithreading. Even [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) says:

> The `Runnable` interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread.

Someone [already asked similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973294/function-with-no-args-and-no-return-type-void-in-java-8) 2 years ago and if you take a look at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973294/function-with-no-args-and-no-return-type-void-in-java-8?lq=1#comment44339488_27973294) and [Brian Goetz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) reaction to it you will understand that Java language designers came to a conclusion that there is no need to create another functional interface that mimics implementation of `Runnable` interface.

Comment: `Runnable` is intended to encapsulate work that can be done asynchronously. Using it in this context is confusing[citation needed]. If the intention is misinterpreted by other developers it can lead to serious issues. It's been suggested to make your own interface called `Operation`, `Executable` or something along those lines.

Comment: If you're going with the 'Invoke' terminology I suggest the interface name `Invokable` instead, to stay in line with the naming conventions.

Comment: The reason I do not want to user `Runnable` is it raises the co developers eye brows when they see Runnable and create confusion. I will stick with Invokable. But to my surprise there is no such interface is Java8

Comment: Yeah, there should be one in `java.util.function`. Using your custom one instead will be best in this case.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus But does Java8 does not have a functional interface out of the box to handle this? I wonder what made them not to have a functional interface similar to Runnable interface

Comment: @zilcuanu Brian Goetz explained why there is no alternative for `Runnable` interface here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973294/function-with-no-args-and-no-return-type-void-in-java-8?lq=1#comment44339647_27973294 Quote: "I'm sure that the existence of `Runnable` is why the Java designers felt they didn't need to add another functional interface", Brian confirmed that.

Answer (score 11):

There is also the possibility to use `Consumer<Void>`. It could look like this

```
public void init(Consumer<Void> callback) {
    callback.accept(null);
}

init((Void) -> done());
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Consumer as callback interface. Comparing it with the JavaScript language, callbacks are bound with a scope. Therefore, if you make use of Consumer interface then you can pass the scope as parameter to the function.
Ex:

```java
public void startTracer(String tracerName, Event boundEvent) {
    executeOnTracer(tracer -> tracer.startTracer(tracerName, boundEvent));
}
...
private void executeOnTracer(Consumer<Tracer> callback) {
    TracerController tracer = null;
    if (isTracerActive()) {
        tracer = getTracer();
    }
    Optional.ofNullable(tracer).ifPresent(callback::accept);
}
```