# Is there a method reference for a no-op (NOP) that can be used for anything lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

This may sounds like a strange question, but is there a way to refer to a standard no-op (aka null operation, null-pattern method, no-operation, do-nothing method) method for a Lambda in Java 8.

Currently, I have a method that takes a, say, `void foo(Consumer<Object>)`, and I want to give it a no-op, I have to declare:

```
foo(new Consumer<Object>() { 
  public void accept(Object o) { 
    // do nothing 
  }
}
```

where I would like to be able to do something like:

```
foo(Object::null)
```

instead.  Does something like exist?

Not sure how that would work with multi-parameter methods -- perhaps this is a deficiency in the lambdas in Java.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26553481/1441122

Comment: "Null Object" pattern is the name of this (per Martin Fowler's Refactoring book - 1997 and updated in 2018). And yes, it'd be great if most interfaces in the JDK shipped with a public static inner class NULL or NullObject.

Comment: I mean .. Most interfaces in the JDK should ship with a inner class that is a Null Object implementation, and a public static var NULL or NullObject which is an instance of that for all to use, like so: foo = Consumer.NULL;

Comment: Here was as close as I could get staying in the spirit of the JDK designers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76985309/501113

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This is no deficiency.

Lambdas in Java are instances of functional interfaces; which, in turn, are abstracted to instances of Java constructs which can be simplified to *one* single abstract method, or SAM.

But this SAM still needs to have a valid prototype. In your case, you want to have a no-op `Consumer<T>` which does nothing whatever the `T`.

It still needs to be a `Consumer<T>` however; which means the minimal declaration you can come up with is:

```
private static final Consumer<Object> NOOP = whatever -> {};
```

and use `NOOP` where you need to.

Comment: Would be really nice to have this in the Consumer interface itself.

Comment: Or, perhaps they could offer a strongly typed solution, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76985309/501113

Answer (score 42):

In your particular case you could simply do:

```
foo(i -> {});
```

This means that the lambda expression receives a parameter but has no return value.

The equivalent code for a `BiConsumer<T, U>` would be:

```
void bifoo(BiConsumer<Object, Object> consumer) { ... }

bifoo((a, b) -> {});
```

Comment: Can be extends for any number of arguments too:

    foo((a,b) -> {});

etc

Comment: I don't like having to introduce an faked/ignored parameter. It harms readability. I've found this preferrable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76985309/501113

Answer (score 12):

Could [`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) fit your needs?

> Returns a function that always returns its input argument.

Comment: Well, you can say `Consumer<ArbitraryType> c=Function.identity()::apply;` but the question is whether this is really better than `c=ignore->{};`…

Comment: actually i think i like Function.identity()::apply as it doen't intriduce an unused parameter

Comment: might not have been what op was looking for, but this is what i was looking for, thanks!

Comment: I know this is stupid, but I just used `Function.identity()::apply; over (v)->{}` as formatter leaves it in the same line instead of hardbreaking { } XD

Comment: I don't like the whole "ignored input parameter" approach. I prefer accurate and strongly typed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76985309/501113

Comment: You can't use a `Function` as a `Consumer`. You haven't tried this.

Answer (score 10):

You can have your own NOOP implementation, similar to Function.Identity.

```
static <T> Consumer<T> NOOP() {
    return t -> {};
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want a method reference for a method that does nothing, the easiest way is to write a method that does nothing. Notice that in this example I have used `Main::doNothing` when a `Consumer<String>` is required.

```
class Main {

    static void doNothing(Object o) { }

    static void foo(Consumer<String> c) { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(Main::doNothing);
    }
}
```

You could also overload `doNothing` by providing a version using varargs.

```
static void doNothing(Object... o) { }
```

This signature will accept literally any sequence of parameters (even primitives, as these will get autoboxed). That way you could pass `Main::doNothing` whenever the functional interface's method has `void` return type. For example you could pass `Main::doNothing` when an `ObjLongConsumer<Integer>` is needed.

Comment: Can be generic for even more applicability. `static <T, U> U noop(T... a) {return null;}`

Comment: @Radiodef I thought about mentioning that in my answer but decided I didn't like it because you can pass `noop` even in the case where the functional interface's method returns a primitive type, which is asking for a null pointer exception.

Comment: @Radiodef The other unfortunate thing is that the signatures of the versions returning `U` and `void` have the same erasure, so either the methods would have to have different names, or they'd have to be in different classes. Personally I think this *is* a deficiency, and something like `noop` or `doNothing` would fit natually in the `Objects` class.

Comment: All true. I didn't think of the unboxing problem.

Answer (score 6):

If you want something that is *very close to a no-op*, you can use `Objects::requireNonNull`.

Using `x -> {}` also works of course, but your IDE's auto-formatter may try to split it up onto multiple lines.

Comment: IDE's auto-formatter may try to split it up onto multiple lines <-- This is why I came here searching for a solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Note: I have found this [Java Lambda Shapes Reference](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HzSpbHhaB6igjkc0me2hTYehgfNkYCENw7io7IQI9vM/edit?usp=sharing) as a Google Sheet useful.

---

I don't like how the Java design team omitted the notion of a `VoidSupplier`.

I want something that gives me a strongly typed `@FunctionalInterface`, where I don't have to pass an "ignored" parameter to a lambda function (a.k.a. closure) that doesn't `return` anything.

As a result, I created a class that fills in this obvious gap.

```java
public class FunctionUtils {

  private FunctionUtils() {
    //Suppress instantiation
  }

  public static final VoidSupplier NO_OP = () -> {
  };

  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface VoidSupplier {

    void get();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use java.lang.Runnable? It even has the @FunctionalInterface Annotation.

Comment: The `Runnable` interface is terrible in terms of readability.

Almost all source code is read at least an order of magnitude more than written.

Therefore, reducing the time it takes for a future someone (including myself 6 months later) to read through code and understand its implications quickly is of vital importance.

The `Runnable` interface forces the reader to slow down and try to figure out the concurrency/multi-threaded implications of its use. 

Whereas `VoidSupplier` is explicit in what it offers with no concurrency ambiguities.