# Lambda that does absolutely nothing

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, runnable

I needed to have a lambda expression of the functional interface `Runnable` that did nothing. I used to have a method

```
private void doNothing(){
    //Do nothing
}
```

and then use `this::doNothing`. But I've found an even shorter way to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29851525/2711488

Answer (score 101, accepted):

For Runnable interface you should have something like that:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> {};
```

Where:

- `()` because run method doesn't receive args
- `{}` body of run method which in this case is empty

After that, you can call the method

```
runnable.run();
```

Comment: For those of us who want a strongly typed in the spirit of the `@FunctionalInterface`, here's the equivalent : https://stackoverflow.com/a/76985309/501113

Answer (score 52):

The lambda expression I use now is:

```
() -> {}
```

Comment: We had hundreds of these throughout our codebase. It makes refactoring the legal code base frustrating. I reified this pattern with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76985309/501113

Answer (score 17):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)  - `Runnables.doNothing();`

Comment: It's madness to include a library for a 6 character expression. Even if you already had Guava in your dependencies this solution is longer than the simple expression and does not improve readability.

Comment: in my opinion it does improve readibility. You do a static import and in the code you just see "doNothing()". The reader wil understand very quickly  that you intentionally decided to "do nothing". Ofk adding Guava to classpath just for that would be a waste.

Comment: Add a comment to show you intentionally decided to do nothing.

Comment: What about memory allocation, will () -> {} not cause jvm to create new object each time it is invoked, unlike the doNothing which probably refers to singleton object?