# Is there a method reference way to express a (Runnable) lambda that does nothing?

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

I have an AutoCloseable class that executes a Runnable within `close()`, like this:

```
static class Whatever implements AutoCloseable {
    Runnable r;
    public Whatever(Runnable r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        r.run();
    }
}

@Test
public void testAutoClose() throws Exception {
    List<Boolean> updateMe = Arrays.asList(false);
    AutoCloseable ac = new Whatever(() -> updateMe.set(0, true));
    ac.close();
    assertThat("close() failed to update list", updateMe, is(Collections.singletonList(true)));
}
```

The above works nicely. And enables me to have code like

```
new Whatever( () -> foo() );
```

to do "something".

But: there is one case, where, well *nothing* should happen for `close()`. This works:

```
new Whatever( () -> {} );
```

As said, that does the job, yet I am wondering: is there a way to express that "empty Runnable" in any other way, for example using some sort of method reference?

Comment: [`This`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851525/is-there-a-method-reference-for-a-no-op-nop-that-can-be-used-for-anything-lamb) might be helpful

Comment: @michalk Nope, in deed helpful.

Comment: @GhostCat Updated the answer with a method reference option. You may like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

I would overload the constructor with a no-arg version.

```
public Whatever() {
    this(() -> {}); 
}
```

`() -> {}` looks consice and self-explanatory to me.

**Option 2**

As an alternative, you could go with a utility class that defines an empty `Runnable` method

```
public final class EmptyUtils {
    public static Runnable emptyRunnable() { return () -> {}; }
}
```

which you could statically import

```
new Whatever(emptyRunnable());
```

**Option 3**

I find this option particularly interesting (and you asked for a method reference)

```
new Whatever(EmptyRunnable::get);
```

even though it requires to write a (completely) dummy class

```
class EmptyRunnable {
    public static void get() {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about a second constructor that takes no argument?

```
public Whatever() {
    this(() -> {});
}
```

Then just do `new Whatever()`. It's not a direct answer to your question (Java does not really have such a no-op), but its a useful alternative.